# First file name value is taken, however, second file name do not show any value in the input textfield

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, input

Couldn't get a value to second file input field.

Example below:

```js
$(".upload").live("change",function(){
    var filename = document.getElementsByClassName('upload')[0].value;
    var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
    if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName('filename')[0].value = filename;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="upload" type="file"/>
<input class="filename" type="text" />

<input class="upload" type="file"/>
<input class="filename" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('input[type="file"]').live("change",function(){
    var filename = $(this)[0].value;
    var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
    if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
    }
    $(this).next('.filename').val(filename);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="upload" type="file"/>
<input class="filename" type="text" />

<input class="upload" type="file"/>
<input class="filename" type="text" />

<input class="upload" type="file"/>
<input class="filename" type="text" />

<input class="upload" type="file"/>
<input class="filename" type="text" />
```

Comment: .next will not work with a table, what's the solution bro?

Comment: Depends on the hierarchy of your `html`. Post your code with table.

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the value of the first input by doing `getElementsByClassName('upload')[0]`. Just add `getElementsByClassName('upload')[1]`. Here you go:

```
$(".upload").live("change",function(){
var filename = document.getElementsByClassName('upload')[0].value;
var filename1 = document.getElementsByClassName('upload')[1].value;
var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
    filename1 = filename1.substring(lastIndex + 1);
}
document.getElementsByClassName('filename')[0].value = filename;
document.getElementsByClassName('filename')[1].value = filename1;
});
```

Comment: I need an unlimited input file field, not through static way

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in pure javascript without jquery, as your jsfiddle was not using jquery.

```
$(".upload").live("change",function(e){
    var filename = e.currentTarget.value;
    var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
    if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
    }
  e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.value = filename;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".upload").live("change",function(){
    var filename = $(this)[0].value;
    var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
}
   $(this).next('.filename').val(filename);
});
```